# SoapUI: pulling property value into JSON mediatype

Tags: soapui

In SoapUI (REST API), I have extracted the values I need and using the transfer properties window, I stored it into property variable.

Now I need to use the property value in a Json media-type for a POST request. I am not sure how to go about this. Do let me know if you need more information regarding resolving this problem.

Comment: Try the documentation: https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property expansion can be used to achieve what you are looking for.

Here you go:

Save the extracted value to test case level custom property, say MEDIA_TYPE.

In the next REST Test Step,  provide value `${#TestCase#MEDIA_TYPE}`, like shown below:

[image]